# Consuming motions on the google map screen

Tags: android, google-maps, onclick

I'm trying to get the location(lat,lon) upon which the user has clicked on google map, how can this be done?

i tried finding it on the net no luck yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the HelloItemizedOverlay class mentioned below, refer to this [Google Maps Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview) for the exact implementation. This will create markers wherever you click on the mark and will also let the user drag the map and seek places for peek.

```
class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
List<Overlays> mapOverlays = map.getOverlays();
//This is going to be your pointer (you can use whatever image you want as your indicator
final Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.indicator);
map.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
        HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable, HelloGoogleMaps.this);
        GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
            (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
        String lat = Double.toString(p.getLatitudeE6() / (Math.pow(10,6)));
        String lon = Double.toString(p.getLongitudeE6() / (Math.pow(10,6)));
        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Title text", "Body Text");
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
        map.postInvalidate();
        return true;
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is that it overrides the previous onClickListener which makes the map static and there is no getOnClickListener() method so i cannot preserve the previous one, what do you suggest?

Comment: what do you mean by it makes the map static? What would you like to do in your onClickListener() method, because whatever you can do in your onClickListener() method can very easily be imported into the onTouch() method as well, so let me know what functionality you are trying to implement in your onClickListener and I'll tell you how to adapt that into onTouch.

Comment: i want to make the user choose a point in the map, and to mark this point as choosen by showing some indicator on that certain point on the map all that while the user can still drag the map and seek for places to peek, but first i wanted to make sure this works by writing the Lat and Lng to the textView of the touched point, so doing just that would be fine.

Comment: @OfekRon please check my edited code. I've implemented your required features.